# Função append vs javascript

Tags: javascript, append

Tenho uma pagina que gera um formulário dinamicamente
usando `append('texto html');`

Esses inputs que eu gero depois de carregar a pagina por completo, não consigo por eles invocar funcoes js criadas no ready da pagina, ou seja, antes dos inputs existirem.

ex: crio um formulario com nome e cpf e o botao salvar usando append.

No meu script já existe um método `salvar(){}` e na hora que crio o button no onclick, chamo a função salvar(), mas não funciona. Acho que pelo fato do input ter sido criando depois do load da pagina. Tem como fazer algo pra corrigir isso?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
                    $( document ).ready(function() {

$('#confirm_edit').click(function(){

 $('#form_execucao').append('<br class=\"campos bts\" /><br class=\"campos bts\" />');
                                $('#form_execucao').append('<label id=\"bt_print\" name=\"bt_print\" onclick=\"pt()\" style=\"margin-left:5px; height:30px; font: normal 13px Verdana, Arial, Times;\" for=\"salvar\" class=\"btn btn-primary campos bts\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-print\"></i> Imprimir</label>');
                                $('#form_execucao').append('<label id=\"bt_salvar\" name=\"bt_salvar\" onclick=\"sv()\" style=\"margin-left:10px; height:30px; font: normal 13px Verdana, Arial, Times;\" for=\"salvar\" class=\"btn btn-info campos bts\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\"></i> Salvar</label>');

});

                    function pt(){
                        alert('imprimindo');
                    }

                    function sv(){
                        alert('salvando');    
                    }

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Entendi parcialmente Hugo, pode compartilhar os trechos relevantes de código?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código contém erros, por isso não funciona.

1. Tire as barras de escape "\" do `append`. Não são necessárias já que vc tá usando aspas simples como delimitador.
2. Não é necessário `$(document).ready(function(){}`. O `.click()` será atribuído normalmente no carregamento da página.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
$('#confirm_edit').click(function(){
 $('#form_execucao').append('<br class="campos bts" /><br class="campos bts" />');
 $('#form_execucao').append('<label id="bt_print" name="bt_print" onclick="pt()" style="margin-left:5px; height:30px; font: normal 13px Verdana, Arial, Times;" for="salvar" class="btn btn-primary campos bts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Imprimir</label>');
 $('#form_execucao').append('<label id="bt_salvar" name="bt_salvar" onclick="sv()" style="margin-left:10px; height:30px; font: normal 13px Verdana, Arial, Times;" for="salvar" class="btn btn-info campos bts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Salvar</label>');
 });

function pt(){
 alert('imprimindo');
}

function sv(){
 alert('salvando');    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<input type="button" value="ok" id="confirm_edit" />
<div id="form_execucao"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem fazer o bind na linha abaixo do append, ligando o botão com a função já criada

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function save() {
    alert('Save!');
  }

  $('#append').click(function(){
    var btn = '<button id="salvar">Salvar</button>'
    $('#container').html(btn);
    $('#salvar').click(save);
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```